# Spring boot Webflux application runs fine as an app, but fails springboottest trying to create a servlet container context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

The project is being migrated from a mix of spring and jersey to full spring boot webflux

The actual error message is:

```
Type org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer not present
```

Problem is I don't know why the test is trying to spawn this context, and debugging is extremely hard.

The test declaration is:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeStrategies;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"opentracing.sample-rate=1"})
class ReactiveControllerIT {
    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;
```

And the application class

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableReactiveNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableReactiveNeo4jRepositories
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SeoGraphApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SeoGraphApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Even with empty test methods I don't reach the actual method.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Omer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, after many hours of debugging.

this method was the key to the solution:

```java
private WebApplicationType deduceWebApplicationType() {
        if (ClassUtils.isPresent(REACTIVE_WEB_ENVIRONMENT_CLASS, null)
                && !ClassUtils.isPresent(MVC_WEB_ENVIRONMENT_CLASS, null)
                && !ClassUtils.isPresent(JERSEY_WEB_ENVIRONMENT_CLASS, null)) {
            return WebApplicationType.REACTIVE;
        }
        for (String className : WEB_ENVIRONMENT_CLASSES) {
            if (!ClassUtils.isPresent(className, null)) {
                return WebApplicationType.NONE;
            }
        }
        return WebApplicationType.SERVLET;
    }
```

The if regarding the Jersey web environment resulted in true, which eventually made this method return servlet type.

The source of it was usage of error types library in my company which for some odd reason depends on jersey-server and when found, results in a servlet context initialization.
I contacted the authors about it, and worst part is that excluding the server dependency had no effect on the functionality.

Thanks to anyone who spent time on this one.